# Outlook Add-In API does not return contentType of certain files in the Outlook 2016 Desktop client

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have noticed that the Office Add-In API does not return [`contentType`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.3/simple-types?product=outlook&version=v1.3?product=outlook&version=v1.3#AttachmentDetails) for the following file extensions when accessing a mail item from in the Sent folder of the Outlook 2016 Desktop client:

- emf
- dwg
- cur
- otf
- woff
- fla
- zip
- ras
- snag
- svg
- tga
- wfx

Is this intended behavior? If it is a bug where do we report it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. We will open something to fix this in a future version of Outlook. However, some notes:

- In your list, I do not repro this for "zip", it returns "application/x-zip-compressed"
- When we fix the bug, it will likely behave the same as OWA. So if those types return a value in OWA, then it will return a value in desktop, if it does not then it won't. We will also look into adding those types into OWA as well.
- I do not have a time frame of when this bug will be fixed.